# Execute curl command in python script

Tags: python, linux, post, curl

I want to implement this `linux command` in my `PYTHON` script, it returns a `JSON` file:

```
curl -k -u username:password -X POST https://servername/wapi/v1.2/network
/fkqjsdlmfjqslmdfsm:11.221.22.0/24/default?_function=next_availabl_ip -H 
"Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"exclude": ["11.221.22.1", 
"11.221.22.2", "11.221.22.3", "11.221.22.4", "11.221.22.5"], "num": 1}'
```

Comment: May the Force be with you!

Comment: Better than using curl: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests or https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **finally** solved it with `requests`:

```
exclude_data = json.dumps({"exclude": ["11.221.22.1", 
"11.221.22.2", "11.221.22.3", "11.221.22.4", "11.221.22.5"], "num": 1})
url = https://servername/wapi/v1.2/network
/fkqjsdlmfjqslmdfsm:11.221.22.0/24/default?_function=next_available_ip
r = requests.post(url, auth=(user, password), verify=False, data=exclude_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to execute this command using python, you can use

```
    subprocess.call([<curl command>])
```

otherwise you might want to consider using http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/